# How to create two levels Grafana Variable from ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, grafana-variable

I work on creating some Grafana dashboards. At the moment, from ElasticSearch data source.

When I am trying to create a variable in Grafana like the one below:

```
{"find": "terms", "field":  "myServer.name"}
```

I get `None,` instead of getting these names: `heroku`, `k8s`, `aws`.

I tried looking through docs and existing StackOverflow questions, but it is still unclear how I can make it work.
[image]

Am I doing it wrong, or is it Grafana's limitation?

Comment: please show mappings docs object in elastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this query:

```
{"find": "terms", "field":  "myServer.name", "query": "myServer.name:*"}
```

The problem was not in the query itself but the type. If I switch myServer.name from type `text` to type `keyword`, it starts working.

As a result, I need to change the template and reindex my logs in ElasticSearch and Filebeat.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, hope you also understood the concepts :)

Comment: field type is name? can show mappings of docs object